# Using featureCollection to define geometry in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I'm starting to use the GEE Python API and I'm struggling with the translation of some instructions from JavaScript to Python.

I'm using the following code in JS:

```js
var all_alerts  = ee.ImageCollection('projects/glad/alert/UpdResult')
var country     = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017').filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_co', 'CG'));
var alerts_2020 = all_alerts.select('conf20').mosaic().clip(country);  

Export.image.toDrive({
  image:alerts_2020,
  description:'alerts_rdc_2020',
  scale: 30,
  region:country,
  maxPixels: 1e10
})
```

and it work like a charm.
Naive I'd like to make the same with the python API:

```py
def get_alerts(country_code, year):
    country = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017').filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_co', country_code))
    all_alerts  = ee.ImageCollection('projects/glad/alert/UpdResult')
    alerts = all_alerts.select(year).mosaic().clip(country);
    
    file_name = 'alerts_' + country_code + '_' + year
    task_config = {
        'image':alerts,
        'description':file_name,
        'scale': 30,
        'region':country,
        'maxPixels': 1e10
    }
    
    task = ee.batch.Export.image.toDrive(**task_config)
    task.start()

country_code = 'CG'
year= 'conf20'
get_alerts(country_code, year)
```

The task start on my GEE taskboard but rise the following error :

> Error: GeometryConstructors.LineString, argument 'coordinates': Invalid type. Expected type: List. Actual type: FeatureCollection.

which I don't understand because it the exact same call I was making (or so I think).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think adding `.geometry()` after `country` will work:

```
task_config = {
    'image':alerts,
    'description':file_name,
    'scale': 30,
    'region':country.geometry(),
    'maxPixels': 1e10
```